# Vue 3 Reactive Property cant get Array data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I cant use the array of my reactive component, becouse it is in a proxy. I try to get the value in the Proxy with Json.stringfy but get only an empty array. How can i use my array?

```js
//index.js
app.config.globalProperties.$s = reactive({ component: undefined });

export default {
    name: 'component',
    data() {
        return {
            array: [],
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.$s.component = this;
        this.array = [{name: 'test'}];
    },

//   template in child component
    <ul>
      <li v-for="a in $s.parent.array"  <- this is not working becouse my array is in a proxy
      </li>
    </ul>


}

console.log(this.array) -> Proxy { <target>: (1) […], <handler>: {…} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Composition API`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html) for global data storage. The other option  is to use [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/).

### Playground

```js
const { createApp, reactive } = Vue;

const mydata = reactive({ array: [] });

const MyComponent = {
  props: {
      array: {      
        type: Array,
        default: []
      }
  },
  template: `
  My Component: 
  <ul>
      <li v-for="a in array">{{a}}</li>
  </ul>`
}

const App = {
  components: { MyComponent },
  setup() {    
    return { mydata }
  },
  created() {
     this.mydata.array = ['test'];
  }
}
const app = createApp(App);
app.mount('#app');
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.5; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  mydata.array: {{mydata.array}}<br/>
 <my-component :array="mydata.array"></my-component> 
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```